# Code continues to receive input from System.in.read() using Java

Tags: java

For an assignment I have to use System.in.read() to get input from the user. I have to make a calculator that can be used multiple times until the user decides to end it.

```
while(!stop) {
        System.out.println("Enter the first digit.");
        first = askForNumber();
        System.out.println("Enter the second digit.");
        second = askForNumber();
        System.out.println("Enter the operation to perform");
        operation = askForCharacter();
        if(first == 0 && first == second) {
            System.out.println("Calculator closing.");
            stop = true;
        }
        if(operation == '+') {
            System.out.println(first + second);
        }
        else if(operation == '-') {
            System.out.println(first - second);
        }
        else if(operation == '*') {
            System.out.println(first * second);
        }
        else if(operation == '/') {
            if(second == 0) {
                System.out.println("Cannot divide by zero.");
                System.out.println("Calculator closing.");
                stop = true;
            }
            System.out.println(first / second);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not an operation");
        }
    }
```

But when I run the program I get this error:

```
45
Enter the second digit.
pls enter number
45
Enter the operation to perform
+
90.0
Enter the first digit.
pls enter number
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at lopezProject.LopezProject.askForNumber(LopezProject.java:17)
at lopezProject.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:13)
```

edit (code for askForNumber()):

```
public static double askForNumber() throws java.io.IOException {
    char cByte;
    String entireNumber = "";
    Integer n = 0;
    System.out.println("pls enter number");
    while(true) { //while the user is still entering information
    cByte = (char)System.in.read(); //each byte is being turned into a character
    if ((cByte == ' ') || (cByte == '\n')) {
    break;
    }
    if(java.lang.Character.isDigit(cByte)) {
        entireNumber += cByte; //and added to the str string            
    }
    }
    if(entireNumber != "") {
    n = new Integer(entireNumber.trim()); //turning the string into an integer
    }
    return (double)n.intValue();
    }

public static char askForCharacter() throws java.io.IOException {
    return (char)System.in.read();
    }
```

Comment: you should also add the code for askForNumber()

Comment: Why at one point in the console there is written "pls enter number"? Is that an input?

Comment: @aleb2000 that's coming from askForNumber() and bug is also in that method as Reek pointed out.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add the code for askForNumber();

Comment: The stack trace you posted indicates the error comes from the method `askForNumber` but you didn't post any. I suspect that you format the input the user gives without checking if it really is a number. Can you include the method in your post?

Comment: @Jan yes, now that I look at it and the stack trace the problem it's definetly there, but without the code there is nothing we can do.

Comment: Okay I edited the post to include the code. Thanks for the quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

Character in `cByte` you pass to `Integer` is not a digit. Most likely you get some line feed or similar. What you should do is check char for being digit before appending to `entireNumber` and discard if not. To check use `java.lang.Character.isDigit()`.
Additionally you also need to check that `entireNumber` is not empty before passing it to integer. When you read operation you read only single char but you most likely press something after plus so on first pass in `askForNumber()` to integer it's still empty.

And on top of it all, in `askForNumber()` loop, you are breaking away from the loop when you encounter end of line. That would be ok, if that was done consistently everywhere, but it's not what you are doing:
on the first digit ... you type number and hit enter => break,
second digit ... you type number and hit enter => break,
operation ... you type it and hit enter => there's no break, you just read first char from `in` and EOL is trailing there. So on the next round what happens is that you enter while loop, encounter trailing EOL and exit the loop before typing in first number. You need to amend it to exit the loop just if some number is already typed and skip and continue otherwise ... or fix the operation reading function to run in the loop just like the number one does and exit only after correct op is selected.

Also in the code above you do direct comparison of Strings like `entireNumber != ""` ... well it doesn't work that way. `String` is an object and you should call it's `equals()` function to compare it w/ another `String`.

Comment: i changed it using this:
    if(java.lang.Character.isDigit(cByte)) {
   entireNumber += cByte; //and added to the str string   
  }

checking char for being a digit but its still giving me the same error.

Comment: One more thing to check before converting to number. Amended my answer to include it.

Comment: i changed my code and the OP, but now it is producing this error:

Enter the first digit.
pls enter number
4
Enter the second digit.
pls enter number
5
Enter the operation to perform
+
9.0
Enter the first digit.
pls enter number
Enter the second digit.
pls enter number
3
Enter the operation to perform
-
-3.0
Enter the first digit.
pls enter number
Enter the second digit.
pls enter number

after it ran once correctly

Comment: yeah well, this code was riddled with the issues. See solution to the latest in amended answer. You should think more carefully about side effects of what you are doing when writing the code ;) ... but i guess that comes w/ experience only